# Work with OData secured service

Tags: authentication, generator, odata, restlet

I want to generate entity classes and Service class of OData secured service.
In OData Java extension page it is written that I need to use `org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator` class that should get uri and output directory parameters.
But if my OData service is secured the generator instance is not able to generate service classes without username and password of the service.
I did not find any way to pass username and password to generator class.

I get 401 HTTP response code.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In the org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator class, in the method main, 
The following code would clear the credential details set in the setCredentials() method.

```
Service service = new Service(dataServiceUri);
if(service.getMetadata() == null)
{
  errorMessage = "Cannot retrieve the metadata.";
}
```

Kindly provide a solution for this issue as I am currently unable to generate the classes for my rest service as the service is secured with an user password.

I tried the following code to generate the code for my secured service uri:

```
import org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator;
import org.restlet.ext.odata.Service;
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeResponse;
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme;

public class ODataRestletGenerator extends Service {

    public ODataRestletGenerator(String serviceUri) {
        super(serviceUri);
    }

    public static final String APPLICATION_URI = "http://ldcigkd.xxx.yyy.corp:50033/xxx/opu/sdata/IWCNT/CUSTOMER/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Add the client authentication to the call
        ChallengeScheme scheme = ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC;
        ChallengeResponse credentials = new ChallengeResponse(scheme, "user", "pwd");       
        new ODataRestletGenerator(APPLICATION_URI).setauth(credentials);

        String[] arguments = { APPLICATION_URI, "/customer/src" };
        Generator.main(arguments);
    }

    private void setauth(ChallengeResponse credentials) {

        super.setCredentials(credentials);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the org.restlet.ext.odata.Service subclass that is generated by OData extension, you can call setCredentials() and pass an instance of ChallengeResponse including scheme (BASIC?), login (identifier) and password (secret).